# Dictionary with two (or more) languages and change it when code is running

Tags: c++, internationalization

I have to display some sentences on a screen.
However, the language can change if the user want to, so I do not want but I can do that :

```
if(language==1)
{
printf("Hello sir");
}
else if(language==2)
{
printf("Hola senor");
}
```

OR

```
printf("%s",language == 1 ? "Hello sir" : "Hola senor");
```

I do not want that because I have a lot of iterations.
Can I use map or enum and change it during code is running, I was thinking about a things like that :

```
#define MESSAGE_HELLO "Hello sir" OR "Hola senor"
printf("%s",MESSAGE_HELLO);
```

Do you have an idea ? Can you help me please ?

Comment: [`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) or any [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) libraries?

Comment: _"Can I use map or enum and change it during code is running"_ sure?

Comment: Maybe define `struct Localization { string MessageHello; string MessageGoodbye; ... };`, then somewhere create this structure for all languages and fill in the values `Localization eng; eng.MessageHello = "Hello sir"; ...`. Then store them in a `std::map<string, Localization>`

Comment: [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qn9943WvM) is a c++98 quick and dirty technique, but maybe you should rely on a serious internationalization library

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution that fits with my requirements.
I use a .json file with all sentences and the languages I use.

```
{
    "my-encoding": "UTF-8",
    "messages": [
        {
            "MESS_HELLO": {
                "english": "Hello",
                "spanish": "Hola"
            }
        },
        {
            "MESS_GOODBYE": {
                "english": "Bye",
                "spanish": "Adios"
            }
        },
        .......
        ]
}
```

To use .json file in C++, I included [json-c lib](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) in my project.

After loading the json file, I put it in a

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>> m_myTable;
```

With an ID declared in cpp (same as MESS_HELLO or MESS_GOODBYE).
It looks like that :

```
//"MESS_HELLO"   -> { "english" -> "Hello" ; "spanish" -> "Hola" }
//"MESS_GOODBYE" -> { "english" -> "Bye" ; "other_language" -> "mess_in_other_language" ; +++  }
```

With that type I can do :

- Easily add a new message by changing .json file + declaring in code a new ID
- Modify the text by only change .json file
- Add a new language by adding to .json file + adding several lines in code, but not a big deal.

To display it, I do something like

```
const auto &text_it = m_myTable.find("MESS_HELLO")
const auto &language_it = text_it->second.find("english");

printf("%s",language_it->second); //print Hello
```

Of course, it's in functions and well implemented, but I can't tell more about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some internationalization library that might help you. But here I will focus on how one can solve such a problem. Naturally, you need to have a set of languages, a set of message keys and a relationship between message keys and the languages, which would hold the actual message. Let's see some solutions:

## Language file

You can store english.txt, etc. which would look like this:

```
hello_world="Hello World"
goodbye="Good bye"
```

and some other language, hungarian.txt for example:

```
hello_world="Heló Világ"
goodbye="Viszontlátásra"
```

etc.

Now, you can create an array of `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`, loop the languages, for each language process the corresponding file and fill the map accordingly.

## Database

You can store a languages table, a message_keys table and a messages table. The messages table would have a foreign key pointing to languages and another one to message_keys and the actual message would be stored there as well. You could have an API that you could use in order to request items or groups of messages in a certain language.

There are many possible solutions.

Comment: Language file seems more appropriate. I didn't understood how can I use Map of string for each languages, and how can I switch of .txt when users want to ?

Comment: @Nawem If you have the languages stored in an array and one language is chosen, then you can load the languagename.txt (like english.txt) if it was not yet loaded. When the user switches language, then you have the language value in the event. That can be used to identify the file that you intend to load.

Comment: @Jarod42 if there are such anomalies, then it follows that you will have a key for Hello and another for Hello world. When two contents differ in languages, then the two contents are not identical.

Comment: It is not an anomaly. In the same way, programming language cannot be translated by simple substitution like that. The meaning of "hello master" from "hello world" might be more explicit in some languages. Normal case is to translate the whole sentence. Placeholder might also be problematic (plural forms depend of language and are generally supported by libraries, but genre (masculine/feminine) are not).

Comment: @Jarod42 by anomaly I've meant the surprise following the naive assumption that two words translated separately should yield the same result as them being translated together. It is certainly seen as an anomaly for whoever sees it for the first time. But, my answer did not state what you started to argue about. The example contained two words in two different languages. It did not state that the combination of their translation is the exact same thing as the translation of their concatenation. So, you are disagreeing with something I did not say.

Comment: @Jarod42 if there was a text for "Hello World", then that should have a separate entry from "Hello" and "World".

Comment: I meant it would be less ambiguous and less error prone for readers to have as example  entries `"hello word"` and `"goodbye"` instead. `"world"` entry would be useful mostly only as title of a world map or as combo box entry, and should NOT be used with `"hello"`. You didn't say it should, but can easily be interpreted like that. that's why I said example is bad.

Comment: @Jarod42 now I see what you mean. Thanks for your patience. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can create two maps for the sentences you want to translate - one map for one language - and then create a pointer to one of the maps. Then use pointer and [] to take sentences you need. Also, the pointer can be changed so that it points to another map at any moment.

Comment: Languages don't translate that easily (I wish they did).  The code needs to translate complete phrases with place holders (if required) for numeric values (etc).

Comment: @RichardCritten Do you mean, you need to translate printed text in runtime? Because if so, I'd say you need some kind of repaint method that would clear old text and print new in another localization.

Comment: Think about how languages phase things differently - verb before noun; verb after noun; where the question mark is; some have genders some don't etc.

Comment: @RichardCritten dude if you really need to translate UI at runtime and your UI is huge and contains a lot of text etc, then you obviously need some special library for that. And I don't actually understand what "different languages have different words order and stuff" stands for. Like, I know three languages and I do know they're different but it's not the programmer's problem, it's translator's problem, and you asked how to program that kind of stuff.

Comment: I think Richard understands *the words* not as "full sentence", but as individual word. The latter is indeed problematic as as `translate("Hello world")` != `translate("Hello") + " " + translate("world")` for most languages.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah, that was my thought too. Well, I mean sentences, not words separately.

Comment: @RichardCritten: It's even worse than just translating placeholders. `"%d items"` doesn't translate to languages where the plural form depends on `%d`. And if the code contains hardcoded logic like `(n==1?"%d item" : "%d items"` it's even worse.

Comment: @MSalters I realise - I have translated large product (on the MS-Windows platform) into most of the European languages - it was a 6 month team efforts including external translators.

Answer (score 0):

In the professional world, I have often used tables (arrays) of phrases.  Each slot in the array represents the phrase in another language.

```
static const char str_hello[] =
{
  /* English */ "hello",
  /* Spanish */ "hola",
  /* German  */ "guten tag",
  //...
};
```

This has worked well in embedded systems.